# jQuery Google Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

How could I replace the Latitude and Longitude in `GLatLng()` with a form control value?

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map = new GMap2($("#map").get(0));
    var burnsvilleMN = new GLatLng(18.502401,-68.391953);
    map.setCenter(burnsvilleMN, 10);
```

Something like this but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map = new GMap2($("#map").get(0));
    var burnsvilleMN = new GLatLng(DOCUMENT.FORM.CONTROL.VALUE);
    map.setCenter(burnsvilleMN, 10);
```

Comment: What is a "form control value"? Is your question to access the value of a form field and pass arguments to functions?

Comment: @zerkms In this case, it's easier to read the code to see what's not working. For starters, he needs two arguments, not just one.

Comment: @Blazemonger: examining and explaining what's not working very often leads to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

borrowing from Blaze a little bit(I forgot that you would need to parse the string for your function GLatLng)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var map = new GMap2($("#map").get(0));
  var longitude = parseFloat($("#longitudeHiddenControl").val());
  var latitude = parseFloat($("#latitudeHiddenControl").val());
  var burnsvilleMN = new GLatLng(longitude, latitude);
  map.setCenter(burnsvilleMN, 10);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Isaac!. How can I used one of "my maps" on my google map account instead of the standard map of google. It that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to retrieve just about any value in the document, but you have to know how to select it. If your form field has an ID attribute, say `id="gmap-lat"`, just select that ID and use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this: `$('#gmap-lat').val();`

Note that you'll need use two values, and convert them into numbers using [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: Thank you Blazemonger !. How can I used one of "my maps" on my google map account instead of the standard map of google. It that possible ?